# What is causing the issue with my WIX installed application?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-8.1

I have two C# winforms applications that are experiencing the same symptoms. I have been using WIX to create installers for these applications for a couple of years without any issues. Now I have a Windows 8.1 computer that will install the software, but when I go to run it gives an error stating "The program has stopped working."

I have used the same exact installers on a number of other computers (Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, and even other Windows 8.1 machines) and they have all installed and ran the software without any issues.

Because of this, I thought it might be an issue with .Net Framework on that one machine. However, I was able to bring the program over as an .exe file instead of an installer and run it without any issues.

I have also tried to run the program with all of the different options in the "Compatibility Troubleshooter" with no luck.

I'm not entirely sure how on-topic this question is, but I could really use some help finding a solution. Does anyone know of anything else I could try to get it to work on this machine?

> UPDATE: I think that the issue may be occurring only with the obfuscated release version of the applications. I recompiled the release version and ran it (both obfuscated and non-obfuscated) on the "bad" machine as well as a couple of "good" machines. The non-obfuscated version worked on all three machines, while the obfuscated one worked only on the "good" machines. Why would this be?

Comment: If I am better off asking this question somewhere else, please let me know.

Comment: Did you log the installation process of the "bad" machine

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I have uninstalled and re-installed multiple times. Every time it goes all the way through the installation wizard as expected and ends up by putting all the expected files in the target directory. The only problem is the .exe file doesn't run...

Comment: You might find an unexpected result in the log file of the installation process.

Comment: I just finished using msiexec to run the msi file on both the "bad" machine and on a "good" machine. I compared the logs and there are no major differences between the two.

Comment: Did you check the event viewer?

Comment: I found the log of the error that occurs whenever I try to run the program. It appears to be an InvalidOperationException being thrown somewhere in mscorlib. Is there a way to pinpoint this even further?

Comment: You can try using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to profile the EXE and it might give you more info about the exception. If you have Visual Studio installed on the "bad" machine you can try to attach the debugger to it and see if there's something you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing the OS fixed the issue. Although this solution was less than ideal, I found that re-installing the .Net Framework and other dependencies did not help the issue and this was the easiest option remaining.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Wix. Make sure when you run a setup, it should run in administrator mode. Without administrator privileges sometimes your installation might not be completed. Registry values, creation of windows services might not be able to do without administrator privileges.

If it's not the cause you should maintain a log file in your application to identify whats the issue. If the machine is missing pre-requisites, make sure you create a bootstrapper and install them before you install your setup.

Answer (score 0):

**Run a file diff** on the installed folder, versus the one you brought manually over to see if there are any obvious differences. Often it is just a config file or a single binary that has not been updated when such problems occur.

Use **Beyond Compare** or a similar disk-diff tool to see what changes are there. Beyond Compare from http://www.scootersoftware.com/ - is hands down a brilliant tool. I use it all the time, and its usefulness is immediate and a tool all professionals working with files would benefit from every day. **Try it**. [**See a screenshot**](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=FolderCompare).

Apart from a missing file update, the question is what is different about the Windows 8.1 PC. Its network connection? Firewall configuration? Did you copy the release or debug version manually? Is visual studio installed on the Windows 8.1 PC? Have you tried dependency walker? Does your exe need admin rights, and if so does it trigger uac? Just some thoughts off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you post the actual error you are getting when the application stopped working but based on what I understand it might be an issue with the installed .Net framework.

You could try to repair/reinstall the .Net framework on the machine where the issue occurred.

Comment: At the time I posted that was literally all I knew. Instead of running the program, it popped up with a message box that said "Program has stopped working." Upon looking further into the situation I have found it to be a CLR20r3 System.InvalidOperationException thrown in mscorlib

Comment: OK so you have the same issue than I also got reported recently. I am still waiting for the customer to get back to me if the re-installation of .Net fixed the problem. You might get the answer before me if you can try it out yourself :-)

Comment: That was one of the first things that I tried. I hope it fairs better for you than it did for me. I am hoping to have access to the computer later today so I can run some more tests. I will let you know if I come across a solution.

Comment: My customer confirmed that re-installing the latest 4.5.2 framework fixed the problem.

Comment: That's good news. I may need to try doing that again to confirm that something didn't go wrong in the process.

Comment: Remember to update the thread whether it fixed your issue or not. It may help others.